# What is “Fast Prime”?

Tags: rsa, terminology, key-generation, roca

In this [note](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/promopages/rsa-update/rsa-background), the manufacturer of a RSA key generation gizmo vulnerable to the new ROCA attack (see second section) explains that

> it is common practice to employ acceleration algorithms in order to generate key pairs, especially if time resources are sparse. (We) also utilizes such an acceleration algorithm in time-restricted cases, called “Fast Prime”. This algorithm is software-based..
>
> The foundations of “Fast Prime” date back to the year 2000. Its use started around ten years later after thorough reviews. As a sub-part of one cryptographic software library which is supplied to customers as a basis for their own development, this software function was certified by the BSI (Federal Office for Information Security) in Germany. No mathematical weaknesses were known, nor have been discovered during the certification processes.

### What is “Fast Prime” and where was it suggested?

The following (likely) tells a property of primes generated by this method; but not how it really works, if that's a deliberate and/or following some article/method, if there was some goof at some point; which I ask.

---

The [ROCA](https://crocs.fi.muni.cz/public/papers/rsa_ccs17) vulnerability/attack targets some RSA keys generated using “Fast Prime”. Details are in the paper: Matus Nemec, Marek Sys, Petr Svenda, Dusan Klinec, Vashek Matyas; [*The Return of Coppersmith’s Attack: Practical Factorization of Widely Used RSA Moduli*](https://crocs.fi.muni.cz/_media/public/papers/nemec_roca_ccs17_preprint.pdf) published at CCS 2017 (in a slightly [earlier version](https://acmccs.github.io/papers/p1631-nemecA.pdf)).

Paraphrasing that article: the factors making the attack possible (presumably, those generated by “Fast Prime” ) are of the form
$$p=k\;M+(65537^a\bmod M) \ \ \text{ where } M=P_n\#=\prod_{i=1}^n p_i$$
with $p_i$ is the $i^\text{th}$ prime.

It follows that any public modulus $N$ made from primes generated in this way is such that $N\equiv65537^a\pmod{P_n\#}$ for some integer $a$.

The integer $n$ is chosen according to the desired bit size of $p$ (which is always multiple of 16), by discrete steps, in a way such that $P_n\#$ is a large fraction of the size of $p$
$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\text{bits in }p & n & p_n & \text{bits in }P_n\#\\
\hline
 256 \dots  480 &  39 &  167 &  220 \\
 496 \dots  976 &  71 &  353 &  475 \\
 992 \dots 1968 & 126 &  701 &  971 \\
1984 \dots 2048 & 225 & 1427 & 1963 \\
\end{array}$$

<sub>A [former version of this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/52292/25) discussed the first published ROCA [test](https://github.com/crocs-muni/roca/blob/master/java/BrokenKey.java#L12) for vulnerable keys. However that's obsolete: it turns out this test was intentionally simplified to limit disclosure about the vulnerability; the [full test](https://github.com/crocs-muni/roca/blob/master/roca/detect.py#L496) has even lower odds of false detection.</sub>

Comment: This looks structurally similar to the [Miller-Rabin Witness test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) for primality.  Are these two approaches mathematically different?  Can Miller-Rabin identify these weak keys as well?  Going forward, should prime generators use both Miller-Rabin and this to test for primality?

Comment: @Russ: in Miller-Rabin, the modulus is the (typically large) number tested, when here the modulus is a small prime; that's a huge difference. Also, it seems the issue in the faulty library is not with the Miller-Rabin test, but in the generation of the prime candidates. My tentative conclusion (without having read the forthcoming paper, or having any insider information whatsoever) is that key generators in general, and the (difficult) RSA ones in particular, must be carefully proofread by multiple eyeballs, in source, object, and debugger; not tested as black boxes.

Comment: The last three paragraphs of the conclusions in the Roca paper suggest that Infineon's algorithm is secret.

Comment: Don't mix up the German term "fast Prim" with the English term "fast prime" (which is short for "fast prime functionality"). While both are related to near-prime numbers, the "fast prime" functionality the Q asks about is about more than just being "fast eine Primzahl" ("almost a prime number" aka "near-prime"). So, rather think of "**fast** prime functionality" as "**speedy** prime generation functionality based on near-primes" instead of trying to interpret things with an incorrect attempt at direct translation based upon erroneous  interpretation that "fast prime" might not be EN.

Comment: @fgrieu In the unlikely case you don't know: the reason for not finding indeep infos about "fast prime" in the certification report is a result of the fact that ***[the security of the “fast prime” functionality … was never part of the evaluation](https://www.rsa.com/en-us/blog/2017-10/roca-blaming-infineon-is-the-easy-way-out)***

Comment: @e-sushi: the _Security Target lite_ matching the _Certification Report_ pointed by the _article_ (links in question) positively includes prime generation. Quoting page 14: _"The software part of the TOE consists of the cryptographic RSA […] libraries […]. The routines are used for the **generation of RSA Key Pairs** (RsaKeyGen) […]"_. AFAIK, the CR is supposed to match the ST or at least explicitly list what of the ST is not covered by the CR. Thus either generation of RSA Key Pairs is certified by the BSI's CR, or the ST lite published by the BSI is a dishonest representation of the real ST.

Comment: @fgrieu I'ld go for the later, even though "dishonest" might be a bit of a strong terminology (even though it somewhat boils down near to it).

Comment: @e-sushi: The _Certification Report_ pointed by the _article_ (links in question) has _"7.1.4.5 Rivest-Shamir-Adleman (RSA) key generation: […] The [Target of evaluation's Security Functions] shall generate cryptographic keys in accordance with a specified cryptographic key generation algorithm rsagen1 (PKCS v2.1 RFC3447) […]"_. Hence some form of on-chip RSA key generation is certified by this CR. Because it has no caveat excluding a "Fast Prime" mode, I conclude that's certified too, if _"Likely RSA v1.02.013 library and later revisions"_ of note 1 in the paper hold.

Comment: Given the timing (2000) and exact title, Maurer's FastPrime method from 1995 and 1999 came to mind.  http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.26.2151.  But you're probably more on track with the CHES2000 reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a tentative guess at answering my own question.

Perhaps the "Fast Prime" method alluded to in the question's citation is that of these two papers (the second polishing the first):

- [JPV2000]: Marc Joye, Pascal Paillier, and Serge Vaudenay; [*Efficient generation of prime numbers*](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/eaae/76a16ace5ddcab098a5be5070fedfa48e707.pdf), in [proceedings of CHES 2000](https://doi.org/10.1007/11894063_13)
- [JP2006]: Marc Joye and Pascal Paillier; [*Fast Generation of Prime Numbers on Portable Devices: An Update*](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/11894063_13.pdf), in [proceedings of CHES 2006](https://doi.org/10.1007/11894063_13) ([slides](https://www.iacr.org/workshops/ches/ches2006/presentations/Marc%20Joye.pdf)).

Several things match:

- The objective of the articles is clearly the one pursued by the technique used.
- "Fast Prime" is two words from the title of [JP2006].
- "date back to the year 2000" is matched by the publication of [JPV2000].
- "use started around ten years later after thorough reviews" allows [JP2006] to get published and reviewed.
- From what we know, the prime generator makes heavy use of an $M=P_n\#=\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n p_i$, essentially as [JPV2000] and [JP2006] do (their $\Pi$ is $M/2$).

However, the technique in [JP2006] is proven to generate almost random primes, and is not susceptible to the ROCA attack. Hence if my theory is right, there has been a serious implementation goof.

The fact that $65537^a$ occurs makes me wonder if the cause of the goof might be a deliberate attempt, gone horribly wrong, to make it faster to compute $e^{-1}\bmod p$ with $e=65537$; or perhaps just insure that it is defined.

---

Update: as noticed in [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/52292/555#comment117447_52843), Daniel J. Bernstein and Tanja Lange's [blog](http://blog.cr.yp.to/20171105-infineon.html) confirms an attempt at implementing [JP2006] gone wrong:

> A related algorithm "GenPrime" was published by Joye and Paillier in 2006. The Joye–Paillier generator, like Lehmer's generator, starts from a new random number $r$ coprime to $L$ and then multiplies repeatedly by a constant $g$ modulo $L$, obtaining $r$ times a power of $g$. This can produce any number modulo $L$, and produces only a slight bias in the resulting primes. The guess was that (company) was oversimplifying and generating merely a power of $g$; this produces far fewer numbers modulo $L$.
>
> The authors wrote back promptly, confirming that this guess was correct but not revealing more details.

Comment: If you apply the algorithm in Fig. 2 of JP2006 on p. 162, with $\Pi = M$, $t = 0$, $v$ drawn at random, $w = 1$ so that $m = w \Pi = M$, and $a = 65537$, and if you always pick $k = 1$ instead of drawing it uniformly at random from $(\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)^\times$ like you're supposed to, then you start with the candidate $q_0 = [(k - t) \bmod m] + t + l = (1 \bmod M) + v M$, and then try $q_1 = (a \bmod M) + v M$, and then $q_2 = (a^2 \bmod M) + v M$, and so on.

Comment: You could test this hypothesis by recovering the exponent of $a = 65537$ from one of the primes in question, and checking whether any smaller exponent is prime.  I wonder whether that observation would accelerate the factoring procedure.

Comment: In fact, the very next section of the paper suggests using $t = b\Pi$ for a randomly chosen $b$, which amounts to the same thing as what I just described.

Comment: It looks like Bernstein and Lange wrote about this on Nov 5:  http://blog.cr.yp.to/20171105-infineon.html.  Lots of interesting info.  They speculated JP2006 and the ROCA authors confirmed this.