# Is RSA vulnerable to possible PRNG + Miller Rabin test weaknesses?

Tags: rsa, prime-numbers, factoring

Factoring a 2048 bit number is a difficult topic with a well known complexity.

But it seems that p, q, the prime numbers used in RSA (order of magnitude: 10^308) are generated thanks to the probabilistic primality Miller Rabin test. Indeed even a table of primes between 10^307 and  10^308 would be out of reach.

Is RSA vulnerable to the potential specific arithmetic properties (if any) of the primes generated during the pseudo random number generator + Miller Rabin process?

Comment: Note that, while use of Miller-Rabin is certainly common, it is not universal; there are other ways of generating primes that are used in practice...

Answer (score 2):

RSA is vulnerable to poor *choice* of the primes of the modulus, and there are quite a few examples of that: RNG that generates the same output on different calls (see [CVE-2008-0166](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=cve-2008-0166), [smartfacts](https://smartfacts.cr.yp.to/) and an example in [usenix 2016's best paper](https://crocs.fi.muni.cz/public/papers/usenix2016)); or dubious mathematical shortcut to make the generation faster (see the [Roca attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/52292/555)).

It is much less common that a bad implementation of the primality *test* cause disaster, because a single iteration of a correct implementation of the Miller-Rabin test is actually quite solid when the number generated is random (see [FIPS 186-4 appendix F](https://doi.org/10.6028/NIST.FIPS.186-4#page=126)); and accidentally choosing a non-prime would most often be caught on the first use of the RSA key: an RSA encryption/decryption is a [Fermat primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test) for its factors, and this has excellent chances of catching a composite.

Comment: `choosing a non-prime would most often be caught on the first use of the RSA key`: I'm not sure to understand: if RSA can catch a composite, then in a way, it's a primality test (you also mentioned this), then why don't we use it instead of Miller Rabin?