# How to find iteration exponent in a cycling attack?

Tags: rsa, cryptanalysis

In Simmons and Norris paper they demonstrate the cycling attack with the following example:

> p = 383 q = 563 s = 49 and t = 56957 ( a prime)
>
> The attacker knows the publicly available r = pq = 215,629 , s = 49
> and an encrypted message C. By forming C<sub>1</sub> = C<sup>49</sup>
> , C<sub>2</sub> = C<sub>1</sub><sup>49</sup>, etc. He will find
> C<sub>j</sub> = C for 1,2,5 or 10

I do not understand how they figured out they will have M = C<sub>j-1</sub> in at most 10 steps? They do mention that 49 belongs to the exponent 10 mod φ(r) = 214,684 but I am not sure what that means. Could anyone explain? please. Thank you!

Comment: The paper referenced is : Gustavus J. Simmons & Michael J. Norris (1977) PRELIMINARY COMMENTS ON THE M.I.T. PUBLIC-KEY CRYPTOSYSTEM, Cryptologia, 1:4, 406-414, [paywalled](https://doi.org/10.1080/0161-117791833219).

Comment: [Cycle attack on RSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1572/18298)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cycling attack with encryption exponent $s$ relies on $s$ having small multiplicative order modulo the multiplicative order of the ciphertext. If $c^v\equiv 1\pmod{pq}$ and $s^w\equiv 1\pmod v$ then repeatedly encrypting $c$ for $w$ times gives
$$c^{s\times s\times\cdots\times s\times s}\equiv c^{s^w}\pmod{pq}.$$
We know that $s^w=kv+1$ for some $k$ so that
$$c^{s^w}=c^{kv}c\equiv c\pmod{pq}.$$

In your case $pq=215629$ and $s=49$. so we know that $v$ divides $\phi(pq)=214684$. This tells us that $w$ divides the multiplicative order of $s$ modulo 214684. A simple calculation will show that
$$49^{10}\equiv 1\pmod{214684}$$
so that $w$ must divide 10. There will be values of $w$ smaller than 10 for some values of $c$ (e.g. $c=32$).

If we write $\mathrm{ord}(x,m)$ for the multiplicative order of $x$ modulo $m$ (i.e. the smallest integer $t>0$ such that $x^t\equiv 1\pmod m$ then the general expression for the number of iterations is
$$\mathrm{ord}\left(s,\mathrm{ord}(c,pq)\right).$$

Comment: perfect! makes sense. thanks!